# Jquery UI, Drag and drop text into a cursor position inside a text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, quill

I would like to have a user drag variables from a supplied list into a Quill text editor to customise their email message. This works when using a `textarea` but I can't seem to get it to work with the Quill text editor.

```js
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'bubble'
});

$(function() {
  $("#allfields li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "select",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  initDroppable($("#TextArea1"));

  function initDroppable($elements) {
    $elements.droppable({
      hoverClass: "textarea",
      accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        var $this = $(this);

        var tempid = ui.draggable.text();
        var dropText;
        dropText = tempid;

      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.editor_container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#editor {
  background-color: #002b36;
  color: #93a1a1;
  width: 45%;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
}

#preview {
  width: 45%;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin: 0 0 0 5%;
}

#allfields li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.bubble.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.6/quill.js"></script>

<!--jquery UI--->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="editor_container">
  <div id="editor">
    <h1>Dear {{name}},</h1>
    <p>
      This is to notify you that you have passed {{threshold_percent_Value}}% on your {{product}} Mobile Data Bundle
    </p>
    <p>
      Note that once your limit is reached, you might be capped and may not be able to connect. <br>
      <p>Regards,<br>{{ company_name }}</p>
  </div>
  <div id="preview">
    <div class="dragitems">
      <h3>
        <span>Available Fields</span></h3>
      <ul id="allfields" runat="server">
        <li id="node1">{{Name}}</li>
        <li id="node2">{{Address}}</li>
        <li id="node3">{{product}}</li>
        <li id="node11">{{Other4}}</li>
        <li id="node12">{{Other5}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4cvmrodz/4/)

Comment: I can see how this might work in theory, yet it's going to be difficult to slice the current text and append in your variable. The Text Ediotor should have a way to read out the current text and you can write in the new text back without issue. The problem will be to get the text into the right location.

Comment: I also see two versions of jQuery UI in your header. This might cause issues too.

Comment: Forked and updated your fiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/jv4q6wcs/

Comment: @Twisty - Thanks 4 ur update. i see good progress, However i am still battling to place the text were the cursor is, instead of appending at end of the line.

Comment: Current progress: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/jv4q6wcs/120/ As you can see, a single line is working yet a line that wraps is not yet.

Comment: @Twisty - Thanks a lot for your help man, But i decided to take another route.